# How can i add a column to an existing Excel File using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have in my file a bunch of names and adresses and I want to add a column named Barcode on an it which i want to fill with the function generateBareCode()
here is my code :

```
import uuid 
import pandas as pd
def generateBarCode(length):
    return str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')[0:length]
```

thank you

Comment: load excel with pandas into dataframe and just add new column

Comment: use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) to save your excel sheet as a dataframe. Add a new column to the dataframe with your uuids. Then use [DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to write the dataframe to an excel file.